# DD4T 2.0 DCP not de-serializing multi-value embeddable schema field

Tags: web8, content-modeling, dd4t-2

I have a content schema with root element "labelSet" and a single multi-value embeddable schema field with xml name "labels".

The embeddable schema field has a root element "label" and has 2 text fields with xml names "key" and "value" respectively.

I am requesting a DCP (dynamic component presentation) and receive a populated IComponent fully populated with the embedded values but I want to de-serialize this into a strongly typed model using the `IViewModelFactory`.

LabelSet.cs:

```
[ContentModel("labelSet", true)]
public class LabelSet : ViewModelBase
{
    [EmbeddedSchemaField(FieldName = "labels", EmbeddedModelType = typeof(Label))]
    public List<Label> Labels { get; set; }
}
```

Label.cs:

```
[ContentModel("label", true)]
public class Label : ViewModelBase
{
    [TextField(FieldName = "key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [TextField(FieldName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I call...

```
// component is a fully populated IComponent instance
var model = viewModelFactory.BuildViewModel<LabelSet>(component);
```

...I get an instance of my `LabelSet` class but the Labels property is null.

Here is a JSON serialized instance of the IComponent I am trying to serialize:

```
{
  "LastPublishedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "RevisionDate": "2017-01-26T20:55:17",
  "Schema": {
    "Folder": {
      "PublicationId": "tcm:0-7-1",
      "Publication": null,
      "OwningPublication": null,
      "Id": "tcm:7-16-2",
      "Title": "Content",
      "ExtensionData": null
    },
    "RootElementName": "labelSet",
    "PublicationId": null,
    "Publication": {
      "Id": "tcm:0-7-1",
      "Title": "050 Common Website",
      "ExtensionData": null
    },
    "OwningPublication": null,
    "Id": "tcm:7-77-8",
    "Title": "LabelSet",
    "ExtensionData": null
  },
  "Fields": {
    "labels": {
      "Name": "labels",
      "Values": [

      ],
      "NumericValues": [

      ],
      "DateTimeValues": [

      ],
      "LinkedComponentValues": [

      ],
      "EmbeddedValues": [
        {
          "key": {
            "Name": "key",
            "Values": [
              "ApplicationTitle"
            ],
            "NumericValues": [

            ],
            "DateTimeValues": [

            ],
            "LinkedComponentValues": [

            ],
            "EmbeddedValues": null,
            "EmbeddedSchema": null,
            "FieldType": 0,
            "CategoryName": null,
            "CategoryId": null,
            "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:labelSet/custom:labels[1]/custom:key",
            "KeywordValues": [

            ]
          },
          "value": {
            "Name": "value",
            "Values": [
              "DD4T Training"
            ],
            "NumericValues": [

            ],
            "DateTimeValues": [

            ],
            "LinkedComponentValues": [

            ],
            "EmbeddedValues": null,
            "EmbeddedSchema": null,
            "FieldType": 0,
            "CategoryName": null,
            "CategoryId": null,
            "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:labelSet/custom:labels[1]/custom:value",
            "KeywordValues": [

            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "EmbeddedSchema": {
        "Folder": {
          "PublicationId": "tcm:0-7-1",
          "Publication": null,
          "OwningPublication": null,
          "Id": "tcm:7-17-2",
          "Title": "Embeddable",
          "ExtensionData": null
        },
        "RootElementName": "label",
        "PublicationId": null,
        "Publication": {
          "Id": "tcm:0-7-1",
          "Title": "050 Common Website",
          "ExtensionData": null
        },
        "OwningPublication": null,
        "Id": "tcm:7-76-8",
        "Title": "Label",
        "ExtensionData": null
      },
      "FieldType": 4,
      "CategoryName": null,
      "CategoryId": null,
      "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:labelSet/custom:labels",
      "KeywordValues": [

      ]
    }
  },
  "MetadataFields": {

  },
  "ComponentType": 1,
  "Multimedia": null,
  "Folder": {
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-7-1",
    "Publication": null,
    "OwningPublication": null,
    "Id": "tcm:7-21-2",
    "Title": "LabelSets",
    "ExtensionData": null
  },
  "Categories": [

  ],
  "Version": 3,
  "EclId": null,
  "PublicationId": null,
  "Publication": {
    "Id": "tcm:0-7-1",
    "Title": "050 Common Website",
    "ExtensionData": null
  },
  "OwningPublication": {
    "Id": "tcm:0-4-1",
    "Title": "030 Common Content",
    "ExtensionData": null
  },
  "Id": "tcm:7-79",
  "Title": "General",
  "ExtensionData": null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update: I have logged an [issue](https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Core/issues/104) in git hub along with a [pull request](https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Core/pull/105) to fix the issue.

I was obtaining the `IComponent` via an `IComponentFactory` and using the `IViewModelFactory.BuildViewModel<T>(IComponent)` method.

This does NOT work.

If I instead use an `IComponentPresentationFactory` to obtain an `IComponentPresentation` and pass the `IComponentPresentation` to the `IViewModelFactory.BuildViewModel<T>(IComponentPresentation)` method this works correctly.

I can't even use the `IViewModelFactory.BuildViewModel<T>(IComponent)` method and pass the `IComponentPresentation.Component` property as this fails.

It seems that the model builder depends on something present outside the scope of the `IComponent` and/or the method which takes an `IComponent` may have a bug.